# re.sub don't delete specific symbols from string

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

There is the following text:

```
txt = 'model   i love u take with u all the time in ur± ' #chinese hieroglyphs here
```

When I try to remove these hieroglyphs, it turns out the following:

```
txt = re.sub("[±]", '', txt)
txt


'model   i love u take with u all the time in ur\x9f\x93± \x9f\x9f\x98\x8e\x9f\x91\x84\x9f\x91\x9f\x92\x9f\x92\x9f\x92'
```

And when, instead of the characters themselves, I substitute their Unicode codes:

```
txt = re.sub("[\x93±\x98\x8e\x91\x84\x91\x9f\x92]", '', txt)
txt

'model   i love u take with u all the time in ur\x9f\x93± \x9f\x9f\x98\x8e\x9f\x91\x84\x9f\x91\x9f\x92\x9f\x92\x9f\x92'
```

then nothing changes anyway.

How is it possible to remove such symbols in this case?

Comment: Try: ```txt = re.sub("±", "", txt)```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The plus-minus sign still remains. P.S. And how to remove hieroglyphs?

Comment: hm, I tried suggested solution and it worked for me

Comment: The line of code I posted here did work for me, that's why I posted it. Another user verified it to work. Can you please post the exact input you're using? Show the hierogyphs you're trying to remove.